# I want to post to an Instagram story from the Flutter app

Tags: android, flutter, dart, instagram

I'm doing it while watching [this](https://pub.dev/packages/social_share).

> SocialShare.shareInstagramStory(imageFile.path, "#ffffff",
> "#000000", "https://deep-link-url");
> It says, what should I put in "File.pash" here? I wrote the path of the image in "pubspec.yaml" and entered the path as it is, but

```
FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = 'assets/Icon.jpeg' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)
```

I get an error. What is the correct answer?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `rootBundle` to load assets.

```dart
import 'dart:async' show Future;
import 'package:flutter/services.dart' show rootBundle;

Future<String> loadAsset() async {
  return await rootBundle.loadString('assets/config.json');
}
```

Comment: `Exception: FormatException: Invalid UTF-8 byte`
But this is coming out and I'm in trouble ...

I don't think it's strange because the image file isn't processed and it's not a photo I took.